# How can I watch/monitor the position changes (height) of an element in a directive (link)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to understand the best correct way to $watch or bind the height position of an element. I have three divs, showed once per time in different tab (using bootstrap). Each div has a different height, and my component (directive) is after the divs. My goal is to show it only when the div is higher than the current vieport height. Is it possible to do that? Just keep in consideration that my directive can be in different positions at the first visualisation so without scrolling, so watching or binding the scrolling doesn't work for me...

This is the code of my directive:

```
(function(angular) {
  var app = angular.module('pi.core');
  app.directive('piGoUp', [
    '$location',
    '$window',
    '$document',
    function($location, $window, $document) {
      return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
          classes: '@',
          image: '@',
          idElement: '@'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          console.log('goUp', element);

          if (!scope.image) scope.image = 'go-up.svg';

          scope.height = $window.innerHeight;

          angular.element($window).bind('resize', function() {
            scope.height = $window.innerHeight;
            console.log(scope.height);
            console.log($window);
            scope.$digest();
          });
        },
        controller: function($scope, $location, $anchorScroll) {
          $scope.goTo = function(idelement) {
            $location.hash(idelement);
            $anchorScroll();
          };
        },
        template:
          '<div class="pi-go-up {{classes}}"><div class="pi-go-up-text" ng-transclude></div><div><img src="{{image}}" ng-click="goTo(idElement)"></div></div>'
      };
    }
  ]);
})(angular);
```

I would like to hide it basing on its parent div height, or an element height or other solutions you may have..

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using bind, use addEventListener:

```
link: function(scope, element) {
  $window.addEventListener('resize', function() {

    // Do what you need to do here; check parent size versus viewport
    // or element size etc;
  }, false);
}
```

Comment: the div before my element can change height without resizing the window, so that does't work for me...